# Contour Integrals and positively oriented circles

Tags: complex-numbers, contour-integration

If $C_0$ denotes a positively oriented circle $|z-z_0|=R$, then $\int_{C_0}$ $(z-z_0)^{n-1} dz$ = $\left\{
     \begin{array}{lr}
       0  &  n=\pm1, \pm2, ...\\
       2\pi i & n=0\\
     \end{array}
   \right.$

Show that if $C$ is the boundary of the rectangle $0$ $\le$ $x$ $\le$ $3$, $0$ $\le$ $y$ $\le$ $2$, described in the positive sense, then $\int_C$$(z-2-i)^{n-1}dz$ = $\left\{
     \begin{array}{lr}
       0  &  n=\pm1, \pm2, ...\\
       2\pi i & n=0\\
     \end{array}
   \right.$

Comment: Is this homework, or a challenge to us?  If you require our help, on what are you stuck?

Answer (score 1):

For the first part, write

$z=R e^{i \phi}$

for $\phi \in [0,2 \pi)$.

For the second, break $C$ into 4 pieces:

$C_1: z=x$, $x \in [0,3]$

$C_2: z=3+i y$, $y \in [0,2]$

$C_3: z=2 i + x$, $x \in [3,0]$

$C_4: z=i y$, $y \in [2,0]$

Add the 4 pieces together.

Comment: I wasn't sure how to start it and what to integrate.  I will try to integrate the for pieces $C_1$ to $C_4$ and see what I get.

Comment: is this right? For $C_1$ : $\int_0^3 (x-2-i)^{n-1}dx$ 
and $C_2$: $\int_0^2 (3+iy-2-i)^{n-1}dy$
$C_3$: $\int_3^0 (2i+x-2-i)^{n-1}dx$
$C_4: \int_2^0 (iy-2-i)^{n-1}dy$

Comment: On $C_2$ and $C_4$, you need a factor of $i$ from $dz = i dy$.